# Why does pip3 install into /usr/local/bin64 instead of my virtual env, even though it's activated?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, virtualenv

I want dependencies for a project to be installed into a virtual environment. I create it successfully, and activate it, but still installing dependencies results in them installed under **/usr/local/bin64** instead of my virtual env:

```
[ec2-user@machine app]$ virtualenv environment
created virtual environment CPython3.7.10.final.0-64 in 392ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/ec2-user/app/environment, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/ec2-user/.local/share/vi
rtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==21.0.1, setuptools==54.1.2, wheel==0.36.2
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
[ec2-user@machine app]$ source environment/bin/activate
(environment) [ec2-user@machine app]$ pip3 install -r requirements.txt
Collecting anyio==3.4.0
  Using cached anyio-3.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
Collecting appdirs==1.4.4
  Using cached appdirs-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Collecting atomicwrites==1.4.0
  Using cached atomicwrites-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.8 kB)
Collecting attrs==20.3.0
  Using cached attrs-20.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49 kB)
Collecting boto3==1.20.14
...
```

I find packages end up here: `/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages`

But I expected them to be installed inside `~/app/environment`, where my virtual env was created and activated.

I checked the location of pip and pip3, seems correct:

```
(environment) [ec2-user@machine app]$ which pip
~/app/environment/bin/pip
(environment) [ec2-user@machine app]$ which pip3
~/app/environment/bin/pip3
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `pip3` which is in the other environment. Try `pip`. And you can validate with `which pip`.

Comment: I checked, but both seem to be on the correct location. See the update to the answer above. I reran the install with just pip, but same result.

One of my dependencies is newrelic, and when I search the machine I only find it in the global site-packages folder at /usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/newrelic.

Any other ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Mmm, try `python -m pip install ..`